# Java. Как узнать, была ли суббота между двумя unix метками (в секундах)

Tags: java, дата, unix, статистика, calendar

Java. Мне нужно обновлять статистику за неделю, как узнать, была ли суббота между двумя unix метками(в секундах) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если считать,что "суббота" - это интервал времени, то задача сводится к проверке пересечения имеющегося интервала (две unix-метки) c интервалом времени "суббота", следующей за и ближайшей к начальной точке имеющегося интервала:

```
public static boolean dateTimeIntersects(Timestamp dt1Start, Timestamp dt1End, Timestamp dt2Start, Timestamp dt2End) {
        return (dt1Start.compareTo(dt2End) <= 0) && (dt1End.compareTo(dt2Start) >= 0);
    }
```

Интервал "субботы" можно найти следующим образом:

```
        Timestamp saturdayStart = Timestamp.valueOf(
                ZonedDateTime.of(dt1.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneId.of("Z"))
                        .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))
                        .toLocalDateTime() // вероятно, здесь можно как-то упростить...
        );
        Timestamp saturdayEnd = Timestamp.from(saturdayStart.toInstant().plusSeconds(24*60*60 - 1));
```

И полный код метода "а была ли суббота" получается таким:

```
    public static boolean isSaturdayBetween(Timestamp dt1, Timestamp dt2){
        Timestamp saturdayStart = Timestamp.valueOf(
                ZonedDateTime.of(dt1.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneId.of("Z"))
                        .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))
                        .toLocalDateTime()
        );
        Timestamp saturdayEnd = Timestamp.from(saturdayStart.toInstant().plusSeconds(24*60*60 - 1));
        return dateTimeIntersects(dt1, dt2, saturdayStart, saturdayEnd);
    }
```

два простых теста:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
         System.out.println(isSaturdayBetween(Timestamp.valueOf("2021-12-05 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2021-12-07 23:00:00"))); // false, от воскресенья до вторника
         System.out.println(isSaturdayBetween(Timestamp.valueOf("2021-12-03 00:00:00"), Timestamp.valueOf("2021-12-07 23:00:00"))); // true, от пятницы до вторника
    }
```